# Munging Time Series in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, time-series

I want to sort data by the date from latest to earliest. My trouble is that the data i have has dates in `mm-dd-yyyy` text format. I could easily clean this up using `Pandas` in python but don't know the tools available in excel. Even when I try to change the format by hand it does not remove the hyphens.

I believe that due to the poor formatting when I sort on the data it sorts on the month first and years end up grouped together instead of keeping the data chronological.

Something this basic must be an easy fix but I haven't found a tool to use.

Thanks in advance!

Solved using

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A5"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 3), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Which eliminates the hyphen by identifying it as the delimited and breaking each date segment into its own cell.

Very sorry for using \selection\ which I know people hate.

Comment: Have you tried different date formats in excel?

Comment: yeah it doesn't seem to make a difference. I'll take the mm-dd-yyyy and right click/format, and set it as mm/dd/yyy or even March 1, 2015, and it does not change the formatting of the data point. It will still be mm-dd-yyyy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any code to change the text that looks like dates into real dates.

Select the column of dates, then click Data > Text To Columns > Next > Next

In this dialog select Date as the data type and choose the order of MDY if the text shows in month/day/year order. Then hit Finish. All cells will now contain real dates and they can be sorted chronologically.

Comment: Because I have a large number of worksheets and this is a repeated process going forward I need it in code. Luckily I can achieve what you suggested with                                                                                                       Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A5"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 3), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the dates and sort them in the following way:

```
from datetime import datetime
l=["2012-10-09","2011-12-12","2012-10-08","2010-03-03"]
dates=[]
for v in l :
    dates.append(datetime.strptime(v, "%Y-%m-%d" ))
dates.sort()
```

Comment: yeah exactly what I would do in python which I don't have access to.

Answer (score 1):

Ah so you want to do it entirely in Excel, make a new column for each of mm dd and yyyy using vba and date parsing so your dates are actually stored by Excel in its' own internal format  so if 2011-12-12 is in cell A1   =DAY(A1) will give you just the day part in a new column but as I recall I thought Excel was smart enough to sort dates without that (since it actually has the date as a serial # internally), but there you go there is also of course a month and year function... Check the function list under dates...

Answer (score 1):

Do all of the cells refuse to change formatting when you change the date format to mm/dd/yyyy or just some of them? Click on one of the cells that refuses to change and look in the formula bar. If you see something like `'01-01-2015`, the `'` is the culprit here. That tells excel to treat this cell as plain text. If that were in cell A1, try `=DATEVALUE(A1)` in another cell to convert it to a date instead of a string, and you should be able to format that cell however you wish.

Comment: i believe that the cells refused to change formatting due to the hyphen, which is considered a text character similar to a '. I found a way to remove that character from each entry and included it in an edit to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar problem a few days ago. Excel would not accept my command to format a cell as date. I could not find the exact site that I used at that time, but this person is having an identical problem. He mentions two methods in passing, one of which worked for me, and there is a third that is the accepted answer there:

http://www.computing.net/answers/office/excel-will-not-change-a-cell-format-/8764.html

To summarize:

- Edit (F2 key while your cell is highlighted) one of your cells with dates in it and make sure there are
  no spaces or invisible characters
- If that doesn't work, then set the    next column to multiply your
  date column by 1, and then try    converting the next column to Date
  format.

A frustrating solution, I agree.

If all else fails you could try the CDate() function in VBA, since you tagged this question with VBA, but that shouldn't be necessary.